# Filter SQL Query based on Last Values in the resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table name `Sample` with the columns `Id` and `Position`.

```
select ID ,POSITION
from SAMPLE
order by 1
```

Sample :

```
ID  Position
1   GEN2
1   GEN1
2   GEN1

2   GEN4
2   GEN2
2   GEN3
3   GEN1
4   GEN1
5   GEN1
5   GEN1
5   GEN1
5   GEN4
6   GEN1
```

Here I need to select the records based on the below condition...

If the last record of every unique `id` has the value of `GEN1`, then I need to filter and selected in to it.

So I expect the result set as below:

```
ID  Position
1   GEN1
3   GEN1
4   GEN1
6   GEN1
```

Since `id`'s (2,5) don't have the value `GEN1` in last recent record I ignore it...

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no such things as a "last record", unless another column specifies the ordering.  Does your data have such a column?

Comment: In your example you don't have a "last entry" of an id because there is no criteria for a order

Comment: Yes. Sample Table has History_id (Identity column)

Comment: Please add History_id to the sample data in your question.

Comment: you didn't mention the version, but if you're working with SQL Server 2012 or newer, use the last_value function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Im using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `history_id`, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select h.*
from (select h.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by history_id desc) as seqnum
      from history h
     ) h
where seqnum = 1 and Position = 'GEN1';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()` partitioned by `id` and order by `history_id` int descending order in a common table expression:

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY History_id DESC) 
      , *
   FROM Sample 
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE Position = 'GEN1' AND rn = 1;
```

An alternative solution is to use a negated `exists` predicate with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ID, Position
FROM Sample s
WHERE Position = 'GEN1'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Sample 
    WHERE Position <> 'GEN1' 
      AND History_id > s.History_id AND ID = s.ID
    );
```

The version using `row_number` most likely performs better when supported by a proper index (something like: `(id, history_id desc, position)` ).

Comment: I do not think that use of `LAST_VALUE()` is valid.  It won't have the same ability to optimise as the `ROW_NUMBER()` version.  *(Searching for the last value each time, then assigning it to every row, then de-duplicating.)*  Plus, you'd need something like `ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` or, preferably, using `FIRST_VALUE()` and a reverse sort order.

Comment: @MatBailie Actually it did return the desired result, but I ran into some issues when I added an index, so I removed it from my answer and just kept the working solution.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it wouldn't work, I meant to say that it would be grossly innefficient compared to `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @MatBailie Oh, I misunderstood you then. In any case it would seem it wasn't as good a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda long method so please understand. Also if you a better solution, I would really be happy seeing that as it would help me too!

First i created a temp table with maximum row numbers per ID.

```
SELECT 
   OutTable.row
   , OutTable.[ID]
   , OutTable.Position
INTO #tmp_result
FROM (
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID ASC) as row
      , [ID]
      , Position
   FROM #test 
) AS OutTable
```

and output were like this..

[image]

then, looked up for each id's maximum row, and filter all who's current row = max row AND Position = 'GEN1'

these where the results BEFORE WHERE [max_row] = [row] and Position = 'GEN1'

[image]

```
SELECT 
    ID
    , Position 
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.row
       , t.[ID]
       , t.Position
        , (SELECT MAX(row) FROM #tmp_result WHERE ID = t.ID) AS [max_row]
    FROM #tmp_result t
) AS T
WHERE
    [max_row] = [row]
AND Position = 'GEN1'
```

and this were the results AFTER the WHERE. (with specified columns)

[image]

Comment: This has problems because you filter in the same scope as the `ROW_NUMBER()`.  `{1, GEN2}, {2, GEN1}, {3, GEN2}` => `{2, GEN1}` because of the `WHERE` clause, after which the `ROW_NUMBER()` is applied `{1, 2, GEN1}`.  This means that you're picking the first GEN1 in each ID, rather than picking the ID because its first row is GEN1.

Comment: I believe I specified the "GEN1" as the filter..so there can never be a GEN2 result isn't it?

Comment: If you have three rows: `{id=1, hist_id=1, pos=GEN2}, {id=1, hist_id=2, pos=GEN1}, {id=1, hist_id=3, pos=GEN1}` then `GEN1` isn't the last value in the sequence.  This means that there should be ***no*** results.  Your query will apply the filter ***before*** applying `ROW_NUMBER()`.  This means that you ***will*** get a result.  You should apply `ROW_NUMBER()` first *(By applying your filter in the outer query)*.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it, my bad buddy.